# Find sum of the number series.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

What is the sum of this series: $$S=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}A-A_m,$$ where $A=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ and $A_m=\sum_{n=1}^{m}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$? So $A=-\ln2$. But how to evaluate $S$?

Comment: $A$ would "equal" $-\ln 2$ if the summation started at $1$, but it doesn't. It starts at $n=m$ it seems.

Comment: $A$ is started from $n=1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$A_m=\sum_{n=1}^m(-1)^n\int_0^1 x^{n-1}\,dx=-\int_0^1\frac{1-(-x)^m}{1-(-x)}\,dx\implies A-A_m=-\int_0^1\frac{(-x)^m}{1+x}\,dx$$ which gives immediately $$S=\int_0^1\frac{x\,dx}{(1+x)^2}=\left.\log(1+x)+\frac1{1+x}\right|_0^1=\log2-\frac12.$$

Answer (score 1):

Using the Lerch transcendent special function, we have
$$A_m=(-1)^{m+1} \Phi (-1,1,m+1)-\log(2)$$ which makes
$$S_p=\sum_{m=1}^{p}A-A_m=\sum_{m=1}^{p}(-1)^{m+1} \Phi (-1,1,m+1)$$ and
$$S_p=\frac {a_p}{b_p}-p\log(2)$$ The $a_p$ form the sequence
$$\{1,3,7,35,37,259,533,1599,1627,17897,18107,235391,\cdots\}$$
The $b_p$ form the sequence
$$\{1,2,3,12,10,60,105,280,252,2520,2310,27720,\cdots\}$$

The $b_n$ correspond to sequence [$A334721$](https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C+2%2C+3%2C+12%2C+10%2C+60%2C+105%2C+280%2C+252%2C+2520%2C+2310%2C+27720%2C+25740%2C+24024%2C+%5C+9009%2C+144144&sort=&language=english&go=Search) in $OEIS$ but the $a_n$ are not identified.

But, checked with the [inverse symbolic calculator](http://wayback.cecm.sfu.ca/cgi-bin/isc/lookup?number=0.193147180559945&lookup_type=simple)
$$S_\infty=\log(2)-\frac 12$$

Comment: So the answer is around $0.193$?

Comment: And how can I obtain the same result (I'm only interested in two digits after decimal point) without wolfram mathematica or other math package?